# log4j2 with custom appender and patternlayout not working

Tags: log4j2, apache-kafka, pattern-layout

I am using log4j2 in my web project. I was trying to put logs directly to kafka by extending abstractAppender. As per documentation my understanding is that i can specify patternlayout for a custom appender and with that being set, my logger will send log events to kafka with formatted string but that is not happening.  log4j2.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" packages="com.abc.webservice.log.appender">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L- %X{sessionId}--%X{guid}- %m #]%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <Kafka name="kafka" topic="test">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L- %X{sessionId}--%X{guid}- %m #]%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Property name="metadata.broker.list">127.0.0.1:9092</Property>
            <Property name="serializer.class">kafka.serializer.StringEncoder</Property>
        </Kafka>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="async">
            <AppenderRef ref="kafka" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="kafka" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.abc" level="debug">
<!--            <appender-ref ref="console" level="debug"/>-->
            <!--<appender-ref ref="kafka" level="debug"/>-->
            <!--<appender-ref ref="console" level="error"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="kafka" level="error"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" >     
            <appender-ref ref="kafka" level="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" level="info"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type">
            <appender-ref ref="console" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="kafka" level="info"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="kafka"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If i use console appender then log comes in proper format but when i use custom appender, log is received without format. How can i send logs to kafka with specified paatternlayout.

Please find my appender implementation

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Booleans;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message;

@Plugin(name = "Kafka", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public final class KafkaAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private KafkaManager manager;

    protected KafkaAppender(String name, Filter filter, Layout layout, boolean ignoreExceptions, KafkaManager manager) {
        super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions);
                System.err.println("hello world hello");
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static KafkaAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") final String name, @PluginElement("Filter") final Filter filter,
            @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") final String ignore, @PluginAttribute("topic") final String topic,
            @PluginElement("Properties") final Property[] properties, @PluginElement("layout") final Layout layout) {
        boolean ignoreExceptions = Booleans.parseBoolean(ignore, true);
        KafkaManager kafkaManager = KafkaManager.getKafkaManager(name, topic, properties);
        if (kafkaManager == null) {
            return null;
        }

//                Layout patternLayout = PatternLayout.createLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L- %X{sessionId}--%X{guid}- %m #]%n",
//                        null, null, null, true, false, null, null);  
//                System.err.println(patternLayout.toString());
        return new KafkaAppender(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions, kafkaManager);
    }

    @Override
    public final void start() {
        if (this.getManager() == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No KafkaManager set for the appender named [{}].", this.getName());
        }
        super.start();
        if (this.getManager() != null) {
            this.getManager().startup();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void stop() {
        super.stop();
        if (this.getManager() != null) {
            this.getManager().release();
        }
    }

    public final KafkaManager getManager() {
        return this.manager;
    }

    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        this.lock.lock();
        try {
            String s = event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();
                        Message logEvent1 = event.getMessage();
                        String sp = logEvent1.getFormattedMessage();
                        this.getManager().send(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to write to kafka [{}] for appender [{}].", this.getManager().getName(), this.getName(), e);
            throw new AppenderLoggingException("Unable to write to kafka in appender: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            this.lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Layout<? extends Serializable> getLayout() {
            Layout patternLayout = PatternLayout.createLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L- %X{sessionId}--%X{guid}- %m #]%n",
                        null, null, null, true, false, null, null);      
            return patternLayout;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your custom appender implementation.  Or at least the rest of your log4j2.xml.

Comment: @rewolf, question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class KafkaAppender, your append method should call `getLayout().toByteArray(event)` to format the event.

I noticed that the sample code overrides `getLayout`. I would not recommend this. The AbstractAppender implementation of getLayout returns the configured layout, which allows you to control the layout in configuration without code changes.

```
@Override
public void append(LogEvent event) {
    this.lock.lock();
    try {
        // let the Layout format the data in the LogEvent object
        final byte[] bytes = getLayout().toByteArray(event);

        // then pass the byte[] array with the formatted event to the manager
        // (I assume that your manager provides this method)
        manager.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to write to kafka [{}] for appender [{}].",
               this.getManager().getName(), this.getName(), e);
        if (!ignoreExceptions()) {
            throw new AppenderLoggingException(
                "Unable to write to kafka in appender: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    } finally {
        this.lock.unlock();
    }
}

// I would recommend not to override getLayout.
// The AbstractAppender implementation of getLayout returns the configured
// layout, which allows you to control the layout in configuration
// without code changes.
// @Override
// public Layout<? extends Serializable> getLayout() {...
```

Comment: Thanks Remko, It is working but my understanding from documentation was that layout is applied by default. Here i have to convert the log message specifically, which doesn't looks like the elegant way. Shouldn't layout be applied on log message automatically ?

Comment: The responsibility of an appender is to pick some attributes from the LogEvent object and append them to the destination. Which attributes to pick and how to append are up to the appender, but most of the built-in appenders allow the user to control this via configuration using a Layout. You are free to do things differently.